# Inserting data to two tables at once in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables:

```
table1_id (PK) |  table1_data
```

and

```
table2_id (PK) |  table1_id (FK) | table2_data
```

and they both together have to be created at once to represent single object. Primary keys are auto incremented, so after inserting table1_data when I move on to creating table2, how can I get the correct, freshly created table1_id value to insert there?

I'm doing it in php:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (`table1_data`) VALUES (:data)");
$stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table2 (`table1_id`,`table2_data`) VALUES (:id,:data)");
$stmt2->bindParam(':id', $table1_id); //how can I get the id of row just created above by stmt?
$stmt2->bindParam(':data', $data2);
$stmt2->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) method for that. Call it after executing your first insert, so you get:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (`table1_data`) VALUES (:data)");
$stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
$stmt->execute();

$table1_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

You can then use `$table1_id` in your second query.